# heading text wont appear next to image source

Tags: html, web-development-server

So I am currently making a blog and I wanted an image on the top left corner of the webpage, and right next to it I wanted a h1 tag right next to it. I tried using the span tags but they aren't working, any reason why my code isn't working? Do I need to learn css so I can properly position the text to be right next to the image?

```
 <span>
  <img src="Blocks.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="This image cannot load"><h1>TheCyberJournalist</h1>
  </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, to do that you have to use a very simple css.

Something like this is working:

```html
<span style="display: flex;">
  <img src="Blocks.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="This image cannot load"><h1>TheCyberJournalist</h1>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

`h1` element has `display: block` property - you need to change the display property into `inline`

```html
<span>
  <img src="https://media.newswest9.com/assets/CCT/images/20f11c7a-0e95-4440-af3a-1926cfb5e15a/20f11c7a-0e95-4440-af3a-1926cfb5e15a_360x203.jpg" width="150" height="100" alt="This image cannot load"><h1 style="display: inline">TheCyberJournalist</h1>
  </span>
```